# Проблема с Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[[image]]

[[image: Вот сообственно ошибка]]
TextView.java и другие подобные ресурсовые файлы просто полностью в ошибках. Не могу понять в чем дело. Я там сама ничего не трогала. Проект запускался, а потом резко перестал,выдавая ошибку  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x8

Comment: Build/rebuild project и invalidate cash and restart уже сделали?

Comment: Или, может быть вы Sdk перенесли/удалили?

Comment: В классах фреймворка у всех куча ошибок - это потому что SDK содержит не все исходники Андроида, но на работу приложения это никак не влияет. А у Вас что-то не так с картинкой, которая должна отображаться в `RecyclerView`. Может быть не сделали вариант для нужной плотности? **P.S.** Логи ошибок и код здесь нужно выкладывать текстом, а не скринами.

Comment: @Jarvis_J да, не помогло

Comment: А что у вас в адаптере на 84й строке? Да и весь адаптер выложить не помешало бы.